# How to load javascript function on page load ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used javascript to generate 2D bar-graphs in a HTML page.
When i am trying to load this HTML page containing bar-graph in to a div tag of some other HTML page using jQuery `.load()` function bar-graph (i.e, scripts) are not loading.

Please help on this issue.

For example i have bar-graph in `xyz.html`. 
I am trying to load `xyz.html` in `abc.html` div tag using jquery `.load()` function. 
Bar-graphs are missing.

Hoping for a reply, thanks for help in advance.

Comment: show us the code, or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

You should use iframe and load the html,I think,we can not directly load html in a div.

Comment: Using div innerHTML property , you can load html in a div.Each HTML element has an innerHTML property that defines both the HTML code and the text that occurs between that element's opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the xyz.html output your self or is it created by some 3rd-party app?

If you're generating bar graphs your self, I recommend to generate just the content of body, not the whole site. Then the loading into abc.html should work correctly.

If they are not generated by you, use mhasan advice, but you shouldn't get the whole content oh html tag but only content of body tag.

BTW: have you an example of the script (js and html) somewhere to look at?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use the

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

});
```

to load the script when the page is ready. so you better put the chart generation script 
inside this function in xyz.html (as said in your example).

You can also use `this document.ready` in your abc.html also to load the div.